# After upgrading Ubuntu, Php is not working on Apache/2.4.52

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

After I upgraded Ubunt22.04.1,
It has Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) and PHP 8.1.2 (cli),but couldn't display phpinfo.php page,It is not working
Please help with this

Comment: First, have a look at the error logs. What do you think can anybody help you without any debug information?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It’s Working

```
sudo apt install --reinstall php8.1 libapache2-mod-php8.0 
sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm 
sudo service apache2 restart
```